# Conditional iterative arrow in Latex Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the flow chart below, and would like an arrow like the one added in green with a condition written on top of it 
(but in the same gray color as the other arrows of course)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{big} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=30em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{small} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \quad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[align = center, node distance = 2.5cm, auto, >=latex, %Make the arrow tips latex
    myline/.style={ultra thick,black!50},
    shorter/.style={shorten <=1mm,shorten >=0.5mm}]

    % nodes
    \node [big] (A) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = A] (B) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = B] (C) {Blabla};
     \node[small, below=2.5cm of C.west, anchor=west] (Da) {Blabla};
     \node[small, below=3.7cm of C.east, anchor=east] (Ea) {Blabla};
     \node[small, below of = Da] (Db) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below = 2.5cm of Db.west, anchor=west] (F) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = F] (G) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = G] (H) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = H] (I) {Blabla};

     % Edges
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (A) -- (B);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (B) -- (C);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=2.6cm]C.south west) -- (Da);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (Da) -- (Db);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=8.2cm]C.south west) -- (Ea);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=2.6cm]Db.south west) ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (F);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=2.6cm]Ea.south west) ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-1.8) -| (F);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (F) -- (G);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (G) -- (H);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (H) -- (I);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 5):

The arrow you want could be something like:

```
\draw[myline,->, shorter] (I) --++(-90:15mm)-|([xshift=10mm]G.east) node[pos=.25,above]{some text}--(G);
```

which means, draw from `(I.center)` (but starting at corresponding border) to a point which is `15mm` below (direction `-90` degrees) and move the pen to this point (`++`). Then draw a corner (`-|`)  from this point to another which is `([xshift=10mm]G.east)` and finally ends to `(G.center)` (respecting corresponding border).

The text is centered over horizontal line with `pos=0.25`, because `pos=0.5` always correspond to corners when using `|-` or `-|`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{big} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=30em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{small} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=14em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

%\begin{figure}[!ht]
%  \centering
%  \quad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[align = center, node distance = 2.5cm, auto, >=latex, %Make the arrow tips latex
    myline/.style={ultra thick,black!50},
    shorter/.style={shorten <=1mm,shorten >=0.5mm}]

    % nodes
    \node [big] (A) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = A] (B) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = B] (C) {Blabla};
     \node[small, below=2.5cm of C.west, anchor=west] (Da) {Blabla};
     \node[small, below=3.7cm of C.east, anchor=east] (Ea) {Blabla};
     \node[small, below of = Da] (Db) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below = 2.5cm of Db.west, anchor=west] (F) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = F] (G) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = G] (H) {Blabla};
     \node[big, below of = H] (I) {Blabla};

     % Edges
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (A) -- (B);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (B) -- (C);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=2.6cm]C.south west) -- (Da);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (Da) -- (Db);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=8.2cm]C.south west) -- (Ea);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=2.6cm]Db.south west) ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (F);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] ([xshift=2.6cm]Ea.south west) ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-1.8) -| (F);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (F) -- (G);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (G) -- (H);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (H) -- (I);
     \draw[myline,->, shorter] (I) --++(-90:15mm)-|([xshift=10mm]G.east) node[pos=.25,above]{some text}--(G);

  \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use `node[pos=xx]{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (node1) at (0,0){node 1};


\node[draw] (node2) at (0,-5){node 2};

\draw[-latex] (node2.south) |-
    node[pos=0.75,above]{text 1}
    ($(node2.south east)+(2,-1)$) |- 
    node[pos=0.25,right]{text 2}
     node[pos=0.75,below]{text 3}
     (node1.east)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution for loop is similar to solutions given in answers of *rpapa* and *Ignasi*, but the whole diagram is drawn on more sophisticated way:

- common nodes features is collected in style `base`
- bigger nodes are on chain and connected by macro `join`
- smaller nodes are positioned by help of library `positioning`
- added is new command `suppress join`, which discontinue join's connection between the first and the second part of big nodes

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 11mm and 0mm,
      start chain = going below,
every path/.style = {draw=black!50, ultra thick,
                     shorten <=1mm,shorten >=0.5mm,
                     -Latex}, 
      base/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners, 
                     minimum height=4em, align=center},
       big/.style = {base, text width=30em, on chain, join}, 
     small/.style = {base, text width=14em},
                        ]
% nodes
\node[big] (A) {Blabla};
\node[big] (B) {Blabla};
\node[big] (C) {Blabla};
%
\node[small, below right=of C.south west] (Da) {Blabla};
\node[small, below=of Da]                 (Db) {Blabla};
\node[small, right=2em of $(Da.east)!0.5!(Db.east)$]   (E) {Blabla};
%
\node[big, suppress join,
                below = of Db.south -| C]    (F)  {Blabla Blabla};
\node[big] (G) {Blabla};
\node[big] (H) {Blabla};
\node[big] (I) {Blabla};
% Edges
\draw (C.south -| Da) edge (Da) (Da) edge (Db)
      (C.south -| E)  edge (E)  (F)   --  (G);
%
\draw (Db) |- ([yshift=7mm] F.north) coordinate (Fa) -- (F); 
\draw (E)  |- (Fa) -- (F);
%
\draw[red] (I.south) -- ++(0,-11mm) 
                -| ($(I.east)+(11mm,0)$) node[pos=0.25,above] {add text here}
                |- (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]